# Is ''Subject X doesn't click with me'' correct?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, idioms

Suppose that I want to say ''History never clicked with me'' as I try to convey that I hated the subject in school, is it correct to say that ?

Comment: [*Despite having a very good lecturer, I never really liked Abstract Algebra because **I never really got it***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22because+i+never+really+got+it%22&tbm=bks&ei=bI2ZZLaJO_WRhbIPpOqWoAc&ved=0ahUKEwi27--xgOH_AhX1SEEAHSS1BXQQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=%22because+i+never+really+got+it%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQqQlY5kNg4kdoAHAAeACAAd8BiAG0EZIBBTkuNi4zmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books) clearly distinguishes ***to get = to understand*** from ***to like***. But ***click*** is vague (and easily misunderstood, if that *like/understand* difference matters to your context).

Comment: You may say : "History was definitively not my cup of tea". [*Meaning*](https://www.myhappyenglish.com/free-english-lesson/2022/04/27/not-my-cup-of-tea-an-american-idiom-english-lesson/)

Comment: @Pat You might want to add the [tag:idioms] tag to your question, too

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can say that, but it's less strong than "hated". It means you didn't really like it.

To "click" with someone (it's usually a person, but doesn't have to be) means you get along with them, enjoy each other's company and so on. So if you don't click with someone, it doesn't mean you hate them, just that you don't particularly get along.

So if History never clicked with you, it means you never really enjoyed it, not that you hated it.

There's also a confusing double meaning here, because "click" can also mean "be understood", so to say "History never clicked with me" can also mean "I never really understood History". I think more people will understand it to mean what you intend, but it's likely someone will think you didn't understand it, rather than disliked it.

Comment: As a native US English speaker, I can't imagine a scenario where "history and I never clicked" would be used (rather, it would be "history never clicked for me"); however: were it to be used, "clicked" would still be referring to understanding the subject rather than any question of enjoyment.

Comment: As another native US English speaker, I like @minnmass's suggestion of "___ never clicked _for_ me"

Comment: "History and I never clicked" -> sounds natural to me. It is a metaphorical statement where history is like a person I didn't get along with - hence, emphasizing not that you didn't understand it but (for unexplained or unexplainable reasons) you did not like it (and it did not like you - to continue to the metaphor!).

Answer (score 8):

As a native US English speaker, I would say **no**, because when we say that something *clicked*, we usually mean that we *understood* it, or that two people got along well, or maybe that something worked properly and was a good fit, but not that you simply liked or disliked a subject.

For example,

> [It never clicked with me that my home phone number was under another name...](https://books.google.com/books?id=YqQ2LaRL6vEC&pg=PA213&dq=it%20never%20clicked&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIqpvq7OD_AhWfj4kEHaTDDO4Q6AF6BAgKEAI)

(The speaker never understood or realized the fact)

> [...they let me try my hand at a few stand-up routines, but it never clicked.](https://books.google.com/books?id=1cO8AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA153&dq=never%20clicked&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_utLO7eD_AhXFmokEHby6Byw4ChDoAXoECAUQAg)

(The stand-up comedy never really worked, it was not popular, it wasn't a success)

> [I saw a completely different Richie Barker during his time at Fratton Park; it just didn't click. He is genuinely one of the brightest coaches around – you ask players at other clubs he's worked at – but it doesn't always fit.](https://books.google.com/books?id=_Db_DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT72&dq=didn%27t%20click&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiR3JiY7uD_AhWhFFkFHby2DawQ6AF6BAgHEAI)

(As a coach, he was not a good match for the club)

---

If you are looking for an idiomatic phrase to say that you hated math and didn't do well in the subject you might say that you and math **didn't get along**:

> [Math and I never got along. I always passed math classes by the skin of my teeth.](https://books.google.com/books?id=LIsuEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT58&dq=%22math%20and%20i%20never%20got%20along%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwimjOCI7-D_AhUbg4kEHQaBDuIQ6AF6BAgDEAI)

Comment: You're confusing two meanings of "click". One is to understand, and the other is to get along. The intent here is to get along. "History and I never got along".

Comment: @gotube: The double meaning is precisely the issue. Given that you're talking about a school curriculum, it's highly likely that "click" is going to be interpreted as "understand". Yes, "get along with" is also a possible interpretation of "click", but it's not the likely interpretation and therefore it is best avoided. The answer could be a bit more explicit about this, but it is correct in its conclusion that OP's intended phrasing is not going to be understood the way they intend it to be.